# How does YouTube structure its video screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, youtube, uikit

My guess is that, under the actual video, is one table view, which has two sections.

The first section's header includes the video's title and other details and the rows are the related videos. The second section's header has the comment form and the rows are the comments.

How else could this be done? If the related videos, for example, is a distinct table view, then given that its a scroll view, wouldn't it scroll in place instead of scrolling as part of the overall screen?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open YouTube right click> view page source.   Add see the structure

Do this inside a a video page. You could inspect element also if your in chrome. To mouseover certain elements on the page to see their styling

Ctrl+shift+C will change your mouse action from element click to element selection

Comment: Also I don't think they use tables.    Their video is an iframe.  Their related video  is a div

Comment: I think you need to check out the full set of tags. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has two sections 
In first section it has title descriptions and other information in header and related videos in rows and in second section it has comments heading and comment text box in header and comments in rows

How to implement it

Create 4 cells two header cells and two rows cells